# App working on Nougat+ versions but crashing on Marshmallow and Lollipop

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gradle

This is the error report whenever I launch the app it crashes and says

> Unfortunately, {app-name} has stopped

**java.lang.RuntimeException:**

```
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2339)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2413)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:155)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1317)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5343)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:905)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

**Caused by: android.view.InflateException:**

```
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:763)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:806)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:504)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:414)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:365)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:139)
  at com.khokhar.yousaf.cipher.Splash.onCreate (Splash.java:15)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6010)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1129)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2292)
```

**Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:**

```
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie (Resources.java:2444)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:2384)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:749)
  at android.view.View.<init> (View.java:3742)
  at android.widget.ImageView.<init> (ImageView.java:149)
  at android.widget.ImageView.<init> (ImageView.java:145)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init> (AppCompatImageView.java:71)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init> (AppCompatImageView.java:67)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:181)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:105)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:725)
```

**This is my Splash Screen coding**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //thread for splash screen running
        Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(2500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.d("Exception", "Exception" + e);
                } finally {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class));
                }
                finish();
            }
        };
        logoTimer.start();
    }

}
```

**And this XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/splashScreen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.khokhar.yousaf.cipher.Splash">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/mediumload" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**The drawable image I used is 600x1024 PNG**

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.khokhar.yousaf.cipher">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/cee"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/cee"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "java-lang-programming://android-app-google-plus-demo"-->
                <data
                    android:host="cipherengineers"
                    android:scheme="android-app-cipher-engineers" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Splash"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**My MainActivity is basically webview**

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    WebView webView;
    String url="https://website/";
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1212);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                textView.setText(progress + "");
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                          boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {



                WebView newWebView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
                newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                newWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
                newWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                newWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
                newWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
                view.addView(newWebView);
                WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
                transport.setWebView(newWebView);
                resultMsg.sendToTarget();

                newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                return true;
            }


});

        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebSettings browserSetting = webView.getSettings();
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        browserSetting.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        browserSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browserSetting.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        browserSetting.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        browserSetting.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        browserSetting.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        browserSetting.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        browserSetting.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        browserSetting.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        browserSetting.setSaveFormData(false);
        browserSetting.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        browserSetting.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        browserSetting.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        browserSetting.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
        }else {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        }
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Are You Sure?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.GRAY));

    }
}
```

**I removed background from Splash Screen XML and nothing worked**

**MainActivity XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/loading_screen"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.khokhar.yousaf.cipher.MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="218dp"
        android:progressTint="?android:attr/fastScrollTextColor"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1212"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:animationCache="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="41dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't figure it out.

Comment: have you added the MainActivity to the app's Manifest? Plus please post your MainActivity Code.

Comment: try removing the *background* from *ImageView*

Comment: @ItzikSamara EDITED my post. check it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `background` from **ImageView**

The reason is lower versions are not able to find *ic_launcher_foreground* in the **drawable** directory which actually exists in **drawable-v24.**

Comment: same result. still crashing on launching on Lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the background image and write your ImageView like this

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/mediumload" />
```

Comment: same result. still crashing on launching on Lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

you cant start a new Activity on Background Thread.. since you run new Thread and inside you start a new Activity it will crash..
2 solutions : declare Handler outside the Thread

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

inside the thread run
   `handler.post(new Runnable() { public void run() { startActivity(..) } });`
or use function :

```
RunOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { startActivity(...) } );
```

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: you try to start new Activity on a Thread which is not the main Thread (UI Thread) since Activity is UI Part it should start from mainThread and not background thread